# Does Micrometer library support OpenTsdb as a Monitoring system?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, opentsdb, micrometer

Does Micrometer library support OpenTsdb as a Monitoring system?

If no, is there any third-party library that can work on the top of Micrometer and report metrics to OpenTsdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, there's no direct support or plan for OpenTSDB but you can use Telegraf (especially [OpenTSDB Output Plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/opentsdb)) for OpenTSDB.

See https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/490

UPDATED:

TBH I'm not familiar with Telegraf but it looks to have a similar architectural pattern with Logstash, so I just gave a try. What I have tried as follows:

1. Install and run OpenTSDB:

   $ brew install opentsdb
   $ /usr/local/opt/hbase/bin/start-hbase.sh
   $ /usr/local/opt/opentsdb/bin/start-tsdb.sh
2. Install Telegraf:

   $ brew update
   $ brew install telegraf
3. Generate a Telegraf configuration:

   $ telegraf -sample-config -input-filter statsd -output-filter opentsdb > telegraf-statsd-opentsdb.conf
4. Change the generated Telegraf configuration (`telegraf-statsd-opentsdb.conf`):

   #host = "opentsdb.example.com"
   host = "localhost"
5. Run Telegraf:

   $ telegraf -config telegraf-statsd-opentsdb.conf
6. Setup Micrometer by adding StatsD implementation with Telegraf flavor. See [this branch](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/statsd-telegraf) for a sample but note that [I changed the port for the StatsD (i.e. Telegraf here)](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/blob/statsd-telegraf/src/main/resources/application.properties#L4) to avoid my local port conflict, so the property should be removed unless you change your Telegraf's port.

With the above flow, it seems to work for me.

Comment: I'm a little confused how I can use it. It's not a java library. How can i use it in java application?

Comment: @evgeniy44 I updated my answer to try to show how to use Telegraf for OpenTSDB and in short, you can think it as sort of adapter. Hope that helps.